# Select dropdown works differently

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, dropdown

After duplicating the div, dropdown from duplicated div show hide does not work properly on same div.

Please check the example you will get an idea. 
Also on Duplicating next div hide all icons and as dropdown selected show them.

Tried working on it with next(), parents(), syblings etc does not work  .

```
Here my fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/kgm50e43/10/
```

Comment: Post your code here, use **Snippet**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `this` object instead of other open `selectors`,

Instead of `var MainNav = $('.Inputs-Control').val();` use, `var MainNav = $(this).val();`

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kgm50e43/11/)

Comment: Thats great, and on duplicating how can I make the icons of next div hide and once the options selected it will show up.

Comment: Thanx a ton bro. Been working on it from last hour and you solved in no time. Cheers \m/,

Comment: @Vinayak Glad to help!  :) Happy diwali!